# Maximo escalation schedule

Tags: maximo

I'm wanting to create an escalation to be scheduled every 12 hours at 10 AM.
However, the form for selecting the schedule time is as follows:

Every **_ hour(s) on minute *_***

It doesn't specify what the starting hour is so how can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Create a SQL where clause that schedules to run itself at certain times only. The escalation would have to run more frequently to hit at 10AM and 10PM. So, if your interval of 10AM can have a little slack with as 9:55AM or 10:15AM the [SQL method](http://mygeekdaddy.net/2014/07/21/schedule-a-maximo-escalation-from-6am-to-6pm/) should work.

Option 2: Create two entries for daily. One for 10AM and another for 10PM.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to do that :P but I waited until the time I wanted then enabled the 12 hour cycle. Thanks though.

Comment: That is a clever solution, but I should warn you that if MXServer is ever restarted, the 12 hour cycle may not match your 10AM/10PM cycle. Creating two daily entries for 10AM and another for 10PM ensures the crontasks run at the specific time of day you want.

Comment: added SQL method to run as one escalation but run two times a day.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your requirement - you want to run the job daily 2 times at 10:00 AM and 10:00 PM. What I will do in this situation is - Schedule the job for every **"720 minutes"** and **reload the cron at time 10:00 AM** , if you **preview** you will see the result desired by you.

Comment: What happens when your MXServer is restarted? Will the cron jobs re-run at 10AM or 10PM?

Comment: Reload the cron again at 10:00 AM. If you want to achieve your requirement with single cron instance ;)

Comment: Or I was just thinking, can't you have 2 instances of the same cron task as: 1) Every 1 day(s), at time 10:00 and 2) Every 1 day(s), at time 22:00

Comment: Or I was just thinking, can't you have 2 instances of the same cron task as:

Comment: A cron task can only have one schedule. You can set up hourly but not indicate specific hour to start. Or set daily with a specific time. Try it yourself in Maximo.