# Schedule a Maximo escalation for multiple days?

Tags: cron, websphere, maximo, escalation

Dear Stackoverflow community,

In Maximo (IBM Control Desk) I have an escalation that I would like to run on 00:00 (midnight) on Tuesday and on Thursday. Using the GUI, I can only select one day and not two.

**GUI**
: Every (om de) 1 week (weken) on (op dag) Tuesday (dinsdag) at (op tijdstip) 00:00:00

[image]

This gives me the following expression:

```
1w,0,0,0,*,*,*,3,*,*
```

After Googling a bit I found that this should let me schedule a task on both days at 00:00 :

```
0 0 * * 2,4
```

But Maximo will not let me add the above giving me an error (and returns to the previously expression) :

[image]

This lets me to believe that the cron expression I found on the internet and the expressions that are generated by Maximo have a different format.

How would I, in Maximo, set the proper expression for it to run on Tuesday and Wednesday 00:00?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/scheduling-escalation-run-every-weekday-not-weekends-0

Comment: https://community.ibm.com/community/user/iot/communities/community-home/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=61fdf1c6-98a8-4384-9556-337c397494b9&CommunityKey=3d7261ae-48f7-481d-b675-a40eb407e0fd&tab=digestviewer#bm61fdf1c6-98a8-4384-9556-337c397494b9

Comment: Your googling returned formatting for Unix cron tasks, not for Maximo Cron Tasks.

Comment: This question is a slight variation on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24436716/5368626)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments under the post, I decided to change the query of the escalations to check for the day in the week. I have added the following line of code:

```
and ( dayofweek(current timestamp) = 3 or dayofweek(current timestamp) = 5 )
```

**Source**:
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_dayofweek.asp

```
1=Sunday, 2=Monday, 3=Tuesday, 4=Wednesday, 5=Thursday, 6=Friday, 7=Saturday.
```